# Gamekit and Game Center sample from Apple

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

For some reason, all the Apple's links to Gamekit samples are broken.  I am looking for Apple's Gamekit and Game Center sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/gktapper/Introduction/Intro.html

Try out this one. It's a bit old, though.

What specifically are you interested in? I bet there are a ton of tutorials that cover it.

Comment: In particularly, I am looking for the GKMatch class: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatch_Ref/Reference/Reference.html